# Setting NA correspondingly in two rasters using R

Tags: raster, r

I have two rasters, `r1` and `r2`. I have numerous NA in both of them. I would like to set NA in `r2`, where `r1` `NA` occurs. Meaning for every NA that occurs in `r1`, I would like to set NA to `r2`.

I want to, set the values of r2  to NA that are also NA in r1.

```
r1 #example raster
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10 
1    3  4  NA 6 NA 8 NA NA NA NA NA 
2    NA NA NA NA 9 NA 8 NA NA NA NA 
3    11 NA NA 18 12 NA NA NA NA  NA  

r2
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
1 3  4  4 6 NA 8 NA NA NA NA NA 
2 NA NA NA 19 20 8 NA NA NA NA 
3 11 41 NA 18 12 NA NA 23 NA  NA
```

I am trying this code, but I am pretty sure this code is different of what I want to achieve.

```
 values(r2)[!is.na(values(r1))] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you simply have to remove the exlamation mark from your code: `values(r2)[is.na(values(r1))] <- NA`.
As it could appear that you have taken your example from the answer given by @Simbamanguto to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95481/in-r-set-na-cells-in-one-raster-where-another-raster-has-values), I'll slightly rework that for illustration.

This code chunk generates two 5x5 rasters and randomly assigns a couple of NA values:

```
library(raster)

r1 <- r2 <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5)
values(r2) <- values(r1) <- rnorm(length(r1))
r1[sample(nrow(r1), 2), sample(ncol(r1), 2)] <- NA
r2[sample(nrow(r2), 2), sample(ncol(r2), 2)] <- NA
```

Here are the resulting rasters

```
head(r1)
           1          2           3           4          5
1  1.0598926  0.8196319          NA          NA  0.4586993
2  0.3036980  1.4968189  0.82771661 -0.37759342 -0.1755361
3  1.2989998  1.5523451 -0.65935728  0.75963815 -0.8351898
4 -0.4433606 -0.5095494          NA          NA  0.8854033
5 -0.5648981  0.6860613  0.03633152 -0.04934847  1.2303864

head(r2)
           1          2           3           4          5
1  1.0598926  0.8196319          NA  0.91559487         NA
2  0.3036980  1.4968189  0.82771661 -0.37759342 -0.1755361
3  1.2989998  1.5523451 -0.65935728  0.75963815 -0.8351898
4 -0.4433606 -0.5095494          NA -0.42249969         NA
5 -0.5648981  0.6860613  0.03633152 -0.04934847  1.2303864
```

This snippet then assigns NA to the values in r2 that are at the positions where r1 holds NA

```
values(r2)[is.na(values(r1))] <- NA
```

Giving this result:

```
head(r2)
           1          2           3           4          5
1  1.0598926  0.8196319          NA          NA         NA
2  0.3036980  1.4968189  0.82771661 -0.37759342 -0.1755361
3  1.2989998  1.5523451 -0.65935728  0.75963815 -0.8351898
4 -0.4433606 -0.5095494          NA          NA         NA
5 -0.5648981  0.6860613  0.03633152 -0.04934847  1.2303864
```